# Regular Expression To Find All Structs Defined With a Bit Field

Tags: c++, regex, bit-fields

I need to search all directories in a C++ code base for structures that contain bit fields.  I know this can be accomplished with regular expressions, but have been unable to put together the correct expression to accomplish this.  Basically I need to find any occurrence of struct*{*:*} where "*" is any character.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I believe there is no valid use of `:<whitespace><digits>` in C or C++, aside from bitfields. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @MatsPetersson what about digraphs like `<:` which translate to `[`?

Comment: @rhalbersma, I'd flay anybody writing with those digraps...

Comment: @vonbrand if you have legacy code with a lot of bitfields, then you might also digraphs from waayyy back with antique keyboards

Comment: @rhalbersma, the writers in that case will presumably be long safely dead ;-) [Truth to be told, if some legacy code were to fall in my hands containing such abominations, the third step after dusting off and removing spiderwebs would be to standardize on non-{di,tri}graphs. And perhaps a silent prayer for the poor soul with no decent keyboard. Knew people with Swedish setups, where `{}[]` and such showed as their special vovels... and they could read/write C fluently.]

Comment: @MatsPetersson, for a quick "let's check for them" job (even over hundreds of files) that should be enough.

Comment: @RichardBrown I have read some basic tutorials, and tried some basic regex searches with success.  The closest I've come for this particular problem is as follows: `findstr /s "struct.*{.*:.*}.*" *.h`  This works for any structs that are defined on a single line, but not multi line structs.  I understand the "." does not include newline characters so I tried to include a /s, but still no luck.

Comment: @vonbrand: Yes, I can (since I'm Swedish) read `int main() ä char strÄ100Å = "foobar"; if (strÄ0Å != "f" öö strÄ1Å != "o") fprintf(stderr, "HuhÖn"); printf("Hello, WorldÖn"; return 0; å`

Comment: @KMA: Assuming you don't need something that copes with code written by people who have Swedish/Danish/Norwegian/Finnish/German/French keyboards, after 1989 but not a PC [since the PC moved the national characters up into the "above 128" range, so you could have a bracket and Swedish letters AT THE SAME TIME, which makes a lot of sense], and also assuming you either run through the C preprocessor, or expect at last some of the fields to have numbers, then searching for `:number` should work.

Comment: @Mats Petersson : `foo ? 1 : 2` is the very common counter-example.

Comment: I ended up doing this: `:.*[1-9];` That turned up a few results that were unneeded, but suited my needs well enough.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The .* directly after the `struct` word matches anything, including { and }. So you should, instead, look for any string between `struct` and {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm ignoring the fact that you need a multiple-line match; how to do that differs from platform and regex implementation (have a look at `sed`!)).

The `.*` directly after the `struct` word matches anything, including { and }. Thus, the string `struct s_one {bool a:3;} one; struct s_two {bool b:4} two;` will be just one match. Worse,
    struct one {
      int noBits;
    };

```
int main(void)
{
  return (2>1)?1:0;
}
```

will match, which is not what you want (note the colon within body of the main function. So you should, instead, look for a match having only something valid between the `struct` and opening brace. Try, for example:

```
struct\s+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\s*{ [^}]*:[^}]*}
```

which, in normal English, would translate to: "Search for the word `struct`, followed by one or more whitespaces, followed by a valid identifier name consisting of only the given characters (one or more of them), optionally followed by any number of whitespaces, followed by a curly opening brace (*we're now inside the definition of the struct*), followed by any text except for a curly closing brace (*we don't want to leave the definition*), having a colon somewhere, followed again by any text except for a curly closing brace, followed by the closing brace.

Note that, depending on your parser, you may need to escape the curly braces (they have a special meainig in Regex). Note also that a simpler regex may also suffice (e.g., you could remove anything behind the colon and it would still work), but what I wrote down gives a better idea of how to construct such a regex in general. Also note that this regex does not take into account any forms of comments inside the code (e.g., it does not match

```
struct one // my favorite first struct
{
  bool a:8;
};
```

(because `one // my favorite first struct` does not match the 'valid identifier name' code `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).